# charcode comparison against raw interger and stored value give different results

Tags: javascript

Whenever I compare a charcode from an index to a raw integer i get the proper response. When I store that same integer in a variable and use the variable to make the comparison, my result is different. Why?

```js
    var f = "What a wonderful world";
    
    let newline = 10; //unicode doesnt work '\u000A'; //charcode (10); 
    let space = 32; //unicode doesn't work '\u0020' //charcode (32);
    
    var test = f.charCodeAt(4);
    console.log(test);                          
               //returns 32
    console.log("space");
              //returns " 'is space'"
    if (test === 32)  console.log("number"); 
              //returns "number"
    if (test === space)  console.log("variable"); 
              //false
```

Comment: I moved your code into a stack snippet ( click `<>` in editor) and removed the `return`s and it works fine running it here in the page. The `return` before last `if()` would cause it not to run. You can edit the snippet yourself if you have a different case that demonstrates the issue